# How to store elements locator?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

i am using pytest with selenium for automation tests and POM. I have files with page objects which they inherit from base_page_objects, files with test code and conftest.py where they are all @pytest.fixtures. My question is, how to store for example 200 locators?

```
def current_email(self):
    return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='current-email']")
```

Right now i am using simple method for each locator but i'm guessing that isn't a proper way to store locators. How to store all locators?

Comment: A lot depends on your framework architecture.

Comment: It's something like that:
Folder with pages objects. 
base_page_objects (a file with repeating methods for all pages, e.g. accepting cookies, opening a page) 
Rest of page objects (individual methods for a specific page, as described above in the current_email method)
Folder with tests - I'm using the fixtures created in conftest.py for each page objects file

conftest.py with all @pytestfixtures created from page objects files.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list and append your locator there.

```
list=[]
def current_email(self):
 for i in range(200):
   variable=self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='current-email']")
   list.append(variable)
 print(list)
```

Comment: I guess that's not what I meant. I'm looking for a solution where I can put the locators differently than 1 locator = 1 method. When writing tests, I need to use single locators, e.g. click this, find this, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary greatly depending on the application you are automating and your framework architecture, so it's up to you to decide what will be best.

That being said your current approach is not bad at all. By calling the method every time you want to interact with the element and not storing a reference you minimize the chance of getting StaleElementException.

If you want to have all locators in different files that is easily achievable since all you need is a tuple containing By and the locator itself

```
# locators.py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

current_mail_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='current-email']")
```

Then you import locators into your POM files:

```
from locators import * 

@property   
def current_email(self):
    return self.driver.find_element(*current_mail_locator)
```

Benefits of this approach is that all your locators will be organised neatly into files, so it makes them easier to fix when eventually they change.

It also makes sense to use the @property decorator for these methods that don't require arguments, so you can use them as if they were fields (without "()")

```
current_email.click()
```

Instead of:

```
current_email().click()
```